# ListView: How to correctly define layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I know this topic has been discussed many times, but I find it so confusing so after trying to have a look at SO and Google, I decided to ask.

I have a secondary `Activity` which is called from the main one. The layout is defined as follows (I'm posting what I consider the relevant part, if something additional is needed, just ask for it). Below the code you'll find some screenshots.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Bloqueados" >

  <!-- TextView to set the activity tittle (I'm using a customized theme) -->
  <TextView
    ... />

    <!-- LinearLayout which shows the orange square -->
    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/block_info"
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges_orange"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <EditText
           ... >
      </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- LinearLayout to ask for the user to be blocked -->
    <LinearLayout
       ... >

        <EditText
            ... >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>    

    <!-- Here it goes, the LinearLayout that contains the ListView -->

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
       android:baselineAligned="false"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <!-- This TextView is shown only if the ListView is empty -->
       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/block_empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:paddingLeft="30dp"
         android:text="@string/block_empty"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:textColor="#3085ef" />

       <!-- Else, this ListView is shown --> 
       <ListView
         android:id="@+id/block_list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:scrollbars="vertical" >
       </ListView>

       <!-- Save button -->
       <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_block_save"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:onClick="btn_close"
         android:background="@drawable/botones"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:text="@string/btn_save" />    
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, graphically, this is the former screenshot:

[image: Former screenshow]

Nothing strange here. So let's populate the `ListView` with some items:

[image: Full list]

Ok, still nothing strange, but the screen height is now filled. Let's add another item to the ListView.

[image: Overflowed]

And here goes the problem. The 'Save' button has disappeared (well, it's below the last `ListView` item, but it's beyond the screen layout). I know using a `ScrollView` + `ListView` is a bad practice so even if I have a workaround that works perfectly I want to avoid using it and do things properly. So the question is: How to make the `ListView` start scrolling when the next added item would move the elements below it off the screen layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout_height="wrap_content" means to grow until all the children are shown. Try using layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" instead. Like this:

```
   <ListView
     android:id="@+id/block_list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:scrollbars="vertical" >
   </ListView>
```

Comment: How easy solution have some headaches! :-) Thanks so much! One more question: I'm realizing that in some of the devices I'm testing with, when put at landscape orientation, the height bottom layout matches just a tiny amount of the first list element of the list, making it almost impossible to scroll. That's of course because there other layout elements above the `ListView`. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer if it worked! One option is to create another layout for landscape mode that would have the list-view in a different position. Or you could just make it always stay in portrait.